# I've re-installed Wicher 3 and my backed up savegames won't load

Tags: the-witcher-3

I re-installed my whole PC yesterday and wanted to play Witcher 3, so I created a zip file of my `C:\Users\neon1\Documents\The Witcher 3` folder, which contained all my save games.

However when I fire up the game now, I don't have the option to continue. When I try a new game and try 'Load game' no files are displayed.

How can I 'import' by backed up save games into the game, so that I can continue my gameplay? Losing almost all of the main campaign would be quite a blow, especially as I made the effort to backup my saves.

Comment: Just a sanity check, but did you unzip the folder in the same location?

Comment: Yep, I loaded the game first to ensure the folders were created by the game, and checked the Witcher wiki http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/The_Witcher_3:_Wild_Hunt#Save_game_data_location

Comment: After I think, the first expansion was installed for sure.

Comment: There was some save game issues with pre and post Heart Of Stone but you seem to think it is not that problem.

Comment: Could this be because my Windows username has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I randomly fired up the game today, after verifying my install.

When I went to load game all my old 1.12 version saves were there, and I was able to load my game just fine, and create a new 1.31 version save.

Pretty pleased I've managed to restore 31h of gameplay!

So if you find this question, be sure to update your game and verify your install. Then restore your old save to the correct folder, and fire up the game.